# Codeigniter loading view for error conditions

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a form and in the action function of the form I am using CI form validation and also checking for file type validations. The code is shared below:

```
function index()
    {       
        $data['dropdown'] = lang_dropdown();  // multilanguage dropdown list
        $data['language']=$this->session->userdata('site_language');
        $data['page']='video/upload';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean|max_length[255]');           
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('video_type', 'Video genre', 'required');         
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mlanguage', 'Language', 'required');     
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('length', 'Length', 'required|is_numeric');           
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('trailer', 'Trailer', 'is_numeric');          

        if (empty($_FILES['video']['name']))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('video', 'Video', 'required');
        }       
        else 
        {
            $extn = end(explode(".", $_FILES['video']['name']));

            if($extn!='mpeg' || $extn!='mp4' || $extn!='mpg' || $extn!='mpe' || $extn!='qt' || $extn!='mov' || $extn!='avi' || $extn!='movie' || $extn!='wmv' || $extn!='flv' || $extn!='3gp' || $extn!='mkv' || $extn!='dv' || $extn!='m4u' || $extn!='m4v' || $extn!='mxu' || $extn!='rv' || $extn!='ogv')
            { 
                $data['videomsg']='<span class="error">Please upload a video of supported format</span>';
                $this->load->view('layout/template',$data);  // here not getting redirected even the control comes to this condition
            }
        }

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('link', 'Link', 'max_length[255]');   

        if (empty($_FILES['thumb_image']['name']))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('thumb_image', 'Thumb Image', 'required|max_length[255]');    
        }
        else 
        {
            $imgextn = end(explode(".", $_FILES['thumb_image']['name']));

            if($imgextn!='jpg' || $imgextn!='png' || $imgextn!='jpeg' || $imgextn!='gif' || $imgextn!='bmp' || $imgextn!='jpe' || $imgextn!='tiff' || $imgextn!='tif')
            {
                $data['imgerror']='<span class="error">Please upload an image of supported format</span>';
                $this->load->view('layout/template',$data);
            }
        }
        ..........................................      
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'required|xss_clean|max_length[500]');          
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('keywords', 'Keywords', '');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('accept_terms', '...', 'callback_accept_terms');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="error">', '</span>');

        ..............................


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) // validation hasn't been passed
        {
            $this->load->view('layout/template',$data);
        }
        else // passed validation proceed to post success logic
        {
            ...................................
            ...................................
            redirect('video/upload');
        }
    }
```

If any of the error conditions satisfies, then I want to redirect to *upload* page with appropriate message. The redirection is not working in this condition. The problem is that in the lines,

```
if (empty($_FILES['video']['name']))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('video', 'Video', 'required');
        }       
        else 
        {
            $extn = end(explode(".", $_FILES['video']['name']));

            if($extn!='mpeg' || $extn!='mp4' || $extn!='mpg' || $extn!='mpe' || $extn!='qt' || $extn!='mov' || $extn!='avi' || $extn!='movie' || $extn!='wmv' || $extn!='flv' || $extn!='3gp' || $extn!='mkv' || $extn!='dv' || $extn!='m4u' || $extn!='m4v' || $extn!='mxu' || $extn!='rv' || $extn!='ogv')
            { 
                $data['videomsg']='<span class="error">Please upload a video of supported format</span>';
                $this->load->view('layout/template',$data);
            }
        }
```

If the file uploaded is not a video file, the control comes in the condition, but it won't redirect to the *upload* page. What is happening now is that, it is redirecting to the upload page with `Successfully uploaded the video !` message which will insert data into the database and creates folder.

How can I solve this problem ? I don't need to `redirect()` as I have to pass error messages to the *upload* page. How can I accomplish this. Can anyone help me to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is way too much code here. Please redact code that is not relevant to the question. It would also be nice if you could format the code so that we do not have to scroll horizontally too much (especially the long `if` statements).

Comment: that long if statement is troubling with the ORs ... if the first expression is true it doesn't check the rest

Comment: but that condition is working fine..there is no any issue within it..

Comment: if they upload a file ... that code will not get hit

Comment: the only problem now I am facing is the redirection is not working..upto that line it is working fine..

Comment: can you please do a die(var_dump($_FILES['video']['name'])); before your  if(empty($_FILES['video']['name']))

Comment: returned string(13) "download1.jpg"

Comment: Thansk to all for the help. I solved the problem by setting the error message as  $this->session->set_flashdata() and then redirecting to upload.php page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (!empty($_FILES))
            {
                if ($_FILES["video"]["error"] > 0)
                {
                  echo "<div style='float: left;color:red; padding: 10px; class='file_upload_error'>Error: " . $_FILES["video"]["error"]."</div>";
                  return FALSE;
                }
                $file = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];
                // Validate the file type
                $fileTypes = array('avi','mp4','mpg','mov'); // File extensions
                $fileParts = pathinfo(strtolower($_FILES['video']['name']));
                if (!in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
                    $data['error'] = '<div style="float: left;color:red; padding: 10px;">Invalid file type. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>';
                    $this->load->view('layout/template',$data);
                }
                else{
                    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['video']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.$filename.".".$ext);
                }

            }else{
                $data['error'] = '<div style="float: left;color:red; padding: 10px;" class="file_upload_error">Something went wrong, the file was not uploaded.<br />Please try again later..</div>';
                $this->load->view('layout/template',$data);
            }
```